# hadoop-HDFS datanodes lost files after restarting HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I have restart HDFS namenodes and datanodes. The ClusterID change so I configured properly, but the storageID and the datanodeUuid I don't know where I can found the properly configuration to detect the files of the DFS. I check `df -h` And there are files:

```
ikerlan@172:/opt/hadoop/sbin$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            5,8G  4,0K  5,8G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1,2G  964K  1,2G   1% /run
/dev/vda1       977G  289G  639G  32% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            5,8G  1,3M  5,8G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   36K  100M   1% /run/user
```

But from the HDFS website I can't see any file.